# How can I contribute to the output channel toolbar for my extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on an extension which has an output channel, and I wish to contribute a button/command to the toolbar for that output channel.  I need a way to reference that toolbar as a contribution point, like "view/title", as well as the output channel view.

Perhaps it would look something like this in the package.json:
"output/title": [ "command": "myExtensionOutputChannelView.cmd", "when": "view == output.myExtensionOutputChannelView" ]

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: "contribute a button/command to the toolbar" : where exactly do you want the button?  The `"view/title"`?  Or the Panel buttons to the right of the Output dropdown?

Comment: I would want it next to the dropdown in the Output view container that is located in the Panel area.  So, I guess, yes, if I can reference my extension output channel view, it would go under "view/title."  So maybe I am really asking how to reference that output channel view.  To give more context, this is the object created with vscode.window.createOutputChannel

Comment: The user can select your outputChannel from that dropdown box - I assume you know that but want to make it easier for them with a custom button which does the same thing?

Comment: The button would perform an action unrelated to the output channel itself, but it would only show when my extension's outputChannel is visible.  Right now, the buttons there are Clear Output, Turn auto scrolling Off, Open Log File, Maximize Panel Size, and Close Panel.  And my button would go next to those buttons.

Comment: Like, this is a command I want to contribute on that toolbar, and the "when" clause is when my output channel is visible.  But I don't know how to reference the view for my extension's output channel.

Comment: I don't think you can contribute to the output view, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.views - there is a very limited set of views to which you can contribute.  You can contribute another view to the Panel but that isn't what you want.  And I don't see any way to know which item is selected in the Output dropdown.

Comment: I don't see an `onDidChange/Select...` type of listener for that Output dropdown.  And I looked at the context keys and while you can tell if the Output view is active, no context key tells you which Output option is selected.

Comment: Yea, it looks like its not possible yet.  Thank you for your help and feedback.